# How to find the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(3-2x) \left(1 + \frac{x}{2} \right)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> In the expansion of $(3-2x) \left(1 + \frac{x}{2} \right)^n$, the coefficient of $x$ is $7$. Find the value of the constant $n$ and hence find the coefficient of $x^2$.

I have no idea how to begin to solve this.

Any help is hugely appreciated, thanks.

This question is from the A level Cambridge syllabus (9709/w16/p12).

Comment: $\left(1+\dfrac x2\right)^n=1+\dfrac n2x+$ terms in higher powers of $x$

Comment: Is this from the (IGCSE) Additional Maths syllabus? It will be useful to tell us what you know that is related to this question: see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details.

Comment: Also, please don't use pictures: type the question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) instead.

Comment: Thanks, @TobyMak. I didn't know how I could type in the question, now I do!

Comment: No problem! If you need help on how this site works, you can always ask one of us in the comments below your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming n to be positive, the only way you can "make" an x term is by multiplying a constant with an x term, or vice versa.
What I mean by this is, 3 times some $x^1$ term will yield an x term. Furthermore, $(-2x)$ times the constant ($x^0$) term of the expansion will also yield an x term. Note that all other terms in the expansion will yield only higher powers of x. So you can calculate the term containing x in terms of n and then set it equal to 7. Find n that way. I hope the rest is intuitive :)